# Displaying List on another site under same site collection

Tags: sharepoint-library

I have two subsites under root site, for example English and Arabic.

I have one custom list in English site with workflow column as content type is attached.

Now I want display the above list in Arabic site.

Please give me steps to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The ListViewWebPart has a "WebId" property that allows you to configure which site you want to read the information from.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.listviewwebpart.webid.aspx

The Web Part would need to have both ListId and WebId properties configured. This can be achieved in 2 ways:

- Programmatically: if you're adding the Web Part from code, you can find the Web's ID for the Arabic site and set it to the WebId property of the Web Part.
- Declaratively: another option would be to export a ListViewWebPart added on the "Arabic" site, manually set the WebId on the XML and then upload it to the English site. You can find the Web Id using, for example, PowerShell, or even directly through SharePoint Designer or with 3rd party utilities such as SharePoint Manager.

http://spm.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am able to display the list in arabic site but one of the column is a content type attach to a workflow, this column not displaying anything. i want user to track the workflow status.

Comment: Is that a Lookup column? If it is it should have a WebId property too that needs to be set.

Comment: no its not a lookup column, content type with workflow